# How to get all the attributes and show in the dropdown field in a backend form in magento 2

Tags: product-attribute, collection, magento2.2.2, drop-downs

I have created backend form which  has one dropdown field.
How Do I get all the attributes and show it in a dropdown in magento 2

Comment: Which attribute - product or customer?

Comment: Are you using UI Form?

Comment: No, normal php form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code...

```
 protected $_attributeFactory;

 public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $attributeFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->_attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
    ....
}

public function <func_name>()
{
    $attributeInfo = $this->_attributeFactory->create()->addVisibleFilter();

   foreach($attributeInfo as $attributes)
   {
        $attributeId = $attributes->getAttributeId();
        // You can get all fields of attribute here
        //e.g.  $attributes->getFrontendLabel();
   }
}
```

In above foreach code, you can add options in dropdown as per your requirement.

For filter in above code, I used `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $attributeFactory` and then below code

```
$collection = $this->_attributeFactory->create()->addVisibleFilter();
```

Comment: Thank you, It get the attribute collection but failed to add Visible filter to attribute

Comment: You can modify collection code to add filter.

Comment: I have added but not working . So I have posted as a seperate question see below and answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217420/how-to-add-filter-to-the-collection-of-attributes-in-magento-2

Comment: I have added like below  $attributeInfo = $this->_attributeFactory->getCollection()->addVisibleFilter()->addIsFilterableFilter();

Comment: I edited my answer for filter. Please check.

Comment: Welcome. Glad to hear that it helped you.