# How to add filter to the collection of attributes in magento 2

Tags: attributes, collection, magento2.2.2

**magento 1 code to get all the attributes collection**

```
public function getAttributes()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')->addVisibleFilter()->addIsFilterableFilter();
        return $collection;
    }
```

**I am changing magento1 code to magento 2 like below It get the collection but while applying filters like addVisibleFilter(),addIsFilterableFilter() then it is failed to load the collection.** Please provide me a solution to get all the attributes with filters.

```
protected $_attributeFactory;

 public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attributeFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->_attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
    ....
}

public function <func_name>()
{
    $attributeInfo = $this->_attributeFactory->getCollection()->addVisibleFilter()->addIsFilterableFilter();

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggesting you use**

> \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $attributeFactory

instead of

> \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attributeFactory

Then use

```
$collection = $this->_attributeFactory->create()->addVisibleFilter();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  $collection = $this->_attributeFactory->create();
  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]);
  $collection->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
```